# Adding an -s to a noun

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

I'm reading a history book in German, and it says:

> ... Einig waren sich die Europäer auch im Gegensatz zum Islam, der sich
> auf der Iberischen Halbinsel auf dem Rückzug befand, an der
> Südostflanke Europa**s** aber rasch vordrang...

What is the point (grammatically speaking) of adding an s at the end of Europa in the last line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the genitive case. For proper nouns such as *Europa* it's formed by adding an *-s*. The genitive usually follows the noun it modifies. It can also precede it when it's a proper noun, but not this time. You'd translate the phrase as "Europe's south-eastern flank" or "the south-eastern flank of Europe"; the genitive in German is often translated with either the possessive or the preposition "of".

Comment: It could also have been “an Europas Südostflanke”.

Comment: @Carsten S: Yes. I think *der Südostflanke von Europa* is also possible, but I'm not sure how idiomatic it is in German.

Comment: @RDBury It would be idiomatically correct, but bad style. Using von + Dative can (almost) always be used to replace a genitive object, but it's bad style, particularly when the genitive object is a name (of a place or person).

Comment: @RDBury: "der Südostflanke von Europa" is as possible as "der Hut von meinem Vater" - der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod.